# loop with FireFox imacros Addon

Tags: firefox, imacros

Is there any solution to use imacros scripting functions (`iimset`, `iimplay`,...) without imacros.exe and only with FireFox imacros Addon ?

Indeed, I need to loop through csv datas and play macros for regular use so free version is not a reliable solution and the full version is out of my budget.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you have installed iMacros for Firefox go read all the examples. It shows how to use a data stored in a csv file, among other things

Comment: Some info as to the [JavaScript Scripting Interface](http://wiki.imacros.net/Firefox#Javascript_Scripting_Interface) must be read by you.

Comment: Thank to both of you for the answers. I read all the doc on the wiki and checked all the samples (especially those dealing with loops).  To use Imacros with scripts (js or vbs or whatever), you need the enterprise edition. My task is redundant and for a long period so the 30 days trial is not an option. You cannot make loop (for example get values from a csv file) and fill an html page without scripting interface commands( iimset, iimplay...) which as I said doesn't come with FireFox Addon.

Comment: Having iMacros free extension for Firefox installed, create a **.js** file including these commands and run it from the extension as you run other macros.

Comment: Thanks derloopkat. By commands do you mean iimSet, iimPlay, .... ?

Comment: yes, that's correct.

Comment: derloopkat, thank you for your help, now it's working.